# Change trace to customised color for double axis plotly charts

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to change plotly trace to specified colors. I researched [update_traces](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/) and [multiple_axes](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/) pages but didn't find a way to do it.

Example data

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[40, 50, 60], name="yaxis data"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[4, 5, 6], name="yaxis2 data"),
    secondary_y=True,
)
```

How to change colors to customised colors ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/), I managed to do it in the following way. Add a field `line` inside `go.Scatter` and specify the `color` threin.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[40, 50, 60],
        name="yaxis data",
        line=go.scatter.Line(color="blue"),
    ),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[2, 3, 4],
        y=[4, 5, 6],
        name="yaxis2 data",
        line=go.scatter.Line(color="green"),
    ),
    secondary_y=True,
)
```

This produces the plot as shown below:
[image]